# Vuejs debouncing a watched property and call the store using VueX

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In a basic component, i am trying to debounce a watched property and use the VueX store :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: "search-filters",
    data() {
        return {
            test: 'test'
        }
    },
    watch: {
      linkName: 'checkLinkName',
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            routeLinkName: 'linkName',
        })
    },
    methods: {
        checkLinkName: _.debounce((newVal, oldVal) => {
            console.log(newVal, oldVal, this.test);
            // this.$store.commit('something') is not working too
        }).bind(this)
    }
}
```

I get the old and the new value in `checkLinkName` but i can't access to the test property (or $store, or mapped getter).

I tried something like that : `linkName: _.debounce(this.checkLinkName, 180)`
but it tells that checkLinkName is not a function.

I tried to create my own debounce function :

```
const debounce = function(fn, time, context) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        const functionCall = () => fn.apply(context, arguments);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
    }
};
```

But still got undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into issues with the binding context of `this`, try using arrow notation within the denounce call.

```
data () {
    return {
        debouncer: null
    }
},
created () {
    this.debouncer = _.debounce((newVal, oldVal) => { 
      console.log(newVal, oldVal, this.test)
      this.$store.commit('something')
    }, 250)

    this.debouncer.bind(this)
},
watch: {
  linkName: this.debouncer
},
```

Comment: I've tried and the `console.log` is never called using this method.

Comment: How about with denounce as the watcher handler directly?

Comment: Yeah i've tried this method too and i've got undefined with `this.test`.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the function keyword is this case instead of arrow notation.

Comment: I still got undefined using function keyword

Comment: Ok one more idea, hopefully this update gets you somewhere.

Comment: I think i gonna find another way, it tells me that `linkName` is undefined.. but thanks

Comment: Well you should be watching `routeLinkName` rather than `linkName`

Comment: I find a solution using yours, thanks ! : 
`linkName(newV, oldV) {
                this.debouncer(newV, oldV);
            }`